# Is it possible to enforce a max upload size in Plack::Middleware without reading the entire body of the request?

Tags: perl, http-request, plack, psgi

I've just converted a [PageKit](http://www.pagekit.org/) (mod_perl) application to [Plack](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack).  This means that I now need some way to enforce the POST_MAX/MAX_BODY that [Apache2::Reques](https://metacpan.org/pod/Apache2::Request)t would have previously handled.  The easiest way to do this would probably be just to put nginx in front of the app, but the app is already sitting behind [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) and I don't see how to do this with HAProxy.

So, my question is **how I might go about enforcing a maximum body size in [Plack::Middleware](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Middleware) without reading the entire body of the request first**?

Specifically I'm concerned with file uploads.  Checking size via [Plack::Request::Upload](https://metacpan.org/pod/Plack::Request::Upload) is [too late](https://metacpan.org/source/MIYAGAWA/Plack-1.0033/lib/Plack/Request.pm#L160), since the entire body would have been read at this point. The app will be deployed via [Starman](https://metacpan.org/pod/Starman), so [`psgix.streaming` should be `true`](https://metacpan.org/source/MIYAGAWA/Starman-0.4011/lib/Starman/Server.pm#L225).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a response from [Tatsuhiko Miyagawa](https://metacpan.org/author/MIYAGAWA) via [Twitter](https://twitter.com/miyagawa/status/545255772364353537).  He says, "if you deploy with Starman it's too late even with the middleware because the buffering is on. I'd do it with nginx".

This answers my particular question as I'm dealing with a Starman deployment.

[He also noted](https://twitter.com/miyagawa/status/545257415529091072) that "[rejecting a bigger upload before reading it on the backend could cause issues in general](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/47/)"

Comment: Perhaps not as many problems as allowed the uploads of unlimited size. Surely this can't be the optimal solution?

Comment: For me it's the easiest one.  The app sits behind nginx, which enforces the max_upload size, so it's no longer the app's problem to deal with.  I had wondered if you could enforce it at the application level so that I could test the max_upload size without getting a web server involved, but I'm fine with setting it up this way.